# Playframework2.2でリクエストのプロトコルを取得したい

Tags: scala, playframework

Playframework2.2のリクエスト処理の経路は`GlobalSettings`の`onRouteRequest`を経由した後にActionに処理されると思います。そこで、`onRouteRequest`を使ってアクセス元のプロトコルを取得したいですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか?

```
trait Global extends GlobalSettings {
   override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
     // val p = request // get protocol
     something(p)
   }
}
```

Comment: プロトコルとは、httpかhttpsかwebsocket？などでしょうか？それともGETやPOSTやPUTなどのhttpのメソッド？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
http,httpsなどです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

play 2.3.0 以降だと secure というメソッドがあるのですが、2.2系だと存在しないので、そのメソッドが入った以下のコミット

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/10d6e5a1490c674f

を参考に、ある程度面倒な方法で頑張るしかないかもしれません？

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Commitを参考に実装しようと思います。